# Changing colour of a line in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, line-art

When I draw a rectangle shape in Photoshop it has colour properties.

But when I draw a line it has no colour properties and just uses currently selected colour.

I want to change the colours of lines I have already drawn.  How do I do this?

Comment: If it's on it's own layer, you can double click the layer thumbnail, just like any shape layer. You can also select the shape and select one of the Shape related tools: Path selection tool, for example. Then you'll be able to see: Fill, Stroke and other tool related options at the top. Note that if the line has a stroke that is set inside, it might be blocking the fill color.

Comment: Thanks, double clicking worked.  I think I linked the layers as all lines changed colour at once but that was what I actually wanted :)

Comment: You can add a color overlay layer style.

Comment: Accept and get upvote

Answer (score 3):

You have two basic options:
You can double click on the layer in Layer tab -> Layer style -> Color Overlay
or

You can change the color if you select your shape layer and up there you will see the shape tollbar. Fill option sets the color of the shape.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

On Any of the photoshop version, just press A on your keyboard, 
A bar will be displayed at the top, from there you can twist your shape to whatever you have including changing line color, increasing it thickness. etc.

Comment: This solved the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Select the **Move** tool

[image]

Click on the line to **Select** it

[image]

Now click on **Line** Tool

[image]

On top of your screen click on **Stroke** and chose a color

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As commented under question, pressing **A** solves the problem. The thing is, when you've selected a tool like Move tool (**V**), you're not in control of shape attributes, but you're more in control of object's positions and alignments.

When you select *Direction Selection Tool* or *Path Selection Tool* (**A**), it selects the *part(s) of object* and hence you get the options to alter them.